# How to Send Text to Text Box which have same xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium Webdriver we have three Text boxes. All the text boxes have the same Id, and I want to send some text in the second text box.

This is my code:

```
Driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='testInstanceScan']"));
```

Could anyone please help how to handle Text boxes which have same Id ?
Currently i m using below code which always send same text for all the three text boxes.

```
    List<WebElement> textfield1 = Driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='testInstanceScan']"));
        for(int i=0; i<textfield1.size();i++){
            WebElement local_textfield1=textfield1.get(i);
            String value1=local_textfield1.getAttribute("placeholder");
        if(value1.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {   
        local_textfield1.sendKeys("Amarendra Singh");
        }
        }
```

Comment: WebElement local_textfield1 why you are using this. Please share th URL

Comment: To get and save all the attribute values for the selected xpath.

Comment: what is the error you are getting with above code, to me it look okay

Comment: Share the HTML code for the same

Comment: @Gaurav- above code always send same text for all the three text boxes, but i want to  send text in second text box only.

Comment: Can you check this? //*[@id='testInstanceScan'][2]

Comment: @ santhosh not working

Comment: Find the solution with below code:-

List<WebElement> textfield1 = Driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='testInstanceScan']"));
  for(int i=0; i<textfield1.size();i++){
   WebElement local_textfield1=textfield1.get(i);
   String value1=local_textfield1.getAttribute("placeholder");
  if( i==0 && value1.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
  { 
  local_textfield1.sendKeys("Amarendra Singh");
  }
  else if(i==1 && value1.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
   local_textfield1.sendKeys("Vijay");
  }
  }

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the second textbox.

Method 1: using find elements

```
List<WebElement> textfields = Driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='testInstanceScan']"));
textfields.get(1).sendKeys("Amarendra Singh");
```

Method 2: using xpath

```
WebElement textfield2 = Driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[@id='testInstanceScan'])[2]"));
textfield2.sendKeys("Amarendra Singh");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array like trick to access each element matching the XPath

```
WebElement textField1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[@id='testInstanceScan'])[1]"));

WebElement textField2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[@id='testInstanceScan'])[2]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way I know to do this is to use an XPath to specify the expected ID and placeholder = "" and then specify the index of the element you want.

Given an HTML example of

```
<html>
    <div id="testInstanceScan" placeholder="">e1</div>
    <div id="testInstanceScan" placeholder="">e2</div>
    <div id="testInstanceScan" placeholder="">e3</div>
</html>
```

The code below works

```
List<WebElement> searchBox = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='testInstanceScan'][@placeholder='']"));
System.out.println(searchBox.get(1).getText());
```

and returns

```
e2
```

which is the element that contains the desired ID, empty placeholder attribute value, and is the second element. This form of XPath can be tailored to a lot of different situations to get the desired element in a single pass instead of looping or filtering the collection.

In your case, your final code would look like

```
List<WebElement> textfields = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='testInstanceScan'][@placeholder='']"));
textfields.get(1).sendKeys("Amarendra Singh");
```

If that still doesn't work, you may need a wait.

```
By locator = By.xpath("//input[@id='testInstanceScan'][@placeholder='']");
List<WebElement> textfields = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator));
textfields.get(1).sendKeys("Amarendra Singh");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is yoyr question but what i understand you want to perform operation on textbox which have same xpaths

This is a sample Html which I used for example

```
<html>
    <div id="test" placeholder="">element1</div>
    <div id="test" placeholder="">element2</div>
    <div id="test" placeholder="">element3</div>
 <div id="test" placeholder="">element4</div>
</html>
```

First use `findElements()` to extract all elements and then use if loop to select one and perform operation This is my code

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("URL");
List<WebElement> allElements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='test']"));
for (WebElement tempElement : allElements) {
if(tempElement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("element2"))
{
System.out.println(tempElement.getText()); // you can perform your operations
}
}
```